# Collection_select how to get the selected value and save in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I want some help. i'm doing one small functionality in rails4.0.0. i have model named user and another model team and i have another model Assign . now in assign model ,I have two select boxes i able to get the usernames and teamnames from both models in form using

```
<%=  collection_select(:team, :team_id , Team.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a user"}) %>
```

now i need to get the selected value from this select box and store in assigns table when i submitting the form..
i  don't know how to get this selected value from controller??

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
   has_many :users
end


class Assign < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :team
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Please post the relationships between your models and the controller method responsible for your view.

Comment: see the edited code above..

Comment: Still missing the controller method.

Comment: Entire code is here :https://github.com/fossbalaji/Hrmanagement

Answer (score 0):

Your object name is :assign, not :team.

```
collection_select(:assign, :team_id , Team.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a user"})
```

This should create the proper names for those boxes, so they will be a part of params[:assign]. If you are using `form_for @assign do |f|`, it is even better to use:

```
f.collection_select(:team_id , Team.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a user"})
```

as this should automatically select the right option.

Comment: selected value will be available as params[:assign][:team_id]. Having look at your controller you need to add it to you `permit` call in `assign_params` method, otherwise it will be ignored. Change above is required as well.